# Translating Magento frontend

Tags: magento, csv, translation

Is there a way to easily just translate Magento default frontend through csv file, translating everything would be too time consuming and not really needed as it would make admin panel very confusing for me.

Same question was asked in Magento forums 4 years ago, but there was no easy way to do it at that time, but apparently Mangento team was contacted and they promised to look into it. So has anything changed since then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look into your `/app/locale/en_US` folder. There you have .csv's that do the translating. Everywhere you see `$this->__('Checkout')` or any other string, Magento hits up this folder for specific files that dictate what to replace with "Checkout" and every other string which echo's this way.

In the CSV files, the first field is the text to look for within `$this->__('')`, the second is what to replace it with. You'll also find different language translation files here.

Each CSV is named after the namespace it belongs to. Hence, `Mage_Catalog.csv` contains the translations for all the files that use the `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/` classes and `/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/catalog` template files.

Here, you'll also find `Mage_Adminhtml.csv`, which handles most of the admin translations.

Comment: Alright, I expected as much atleast there's that, those file names get a bit confusing, but I guess it's not really that hard to open it up and read... Thanks a lot for quick reply, I'll start working on them.

Comment: Turn off your cache while testing, you can change a value, save and reload page to make sure you are editing the right file and tag.

Comment: Also of note, when declaring certain values in XML files, there is a `translate=""` attribute you can assign, such as `translate="label"`. This will allow translation of XML assigned values (form labels, etc).

Comment: `app/locale/en_US` is the equivalent of editing core files, overwritable on next upgrade. `app/design/frontend/default/my_template/locale/en_‌​US/translate.csv` will tie it to your custom work and maintain it in case of upgrade.